# Remotly add computer to domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain

Well i have a few computers on my network which is not connected to the domain. I can rdp to each by their IP and add them to the domain manually.

I wonder if I can do this by some windows admintool remotely?
eg. can you send a command to the computer that it should join my domain, just like you can remotely shutdown a computer by cmd: shutdown -i.

Or can I do this from the manage-window?

I haven't found a satisfying answer to this question, neither confirming och denying that it is possible.

Comment: PowerShell `Add-Computer` https://ss64.com/ps/add-computer.html

Comment: Official Documentation for [`Add-Computer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1).